# Performing an Update via a MySQL Aggregate Query

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I am attempting to update a field on a single table with the results of a sum statement from another table. In order to get the results I have to tie together two tables and sum a qty field in one of those two tables. I then need to set the summed qty to a field in a third table. I've looked around for a solution, and have found some answers, but they weren't super detailed answers and I have been unable to make it work for my situation.

I think I'm fairly close to a solution, but my current MySQL query is unable to run. It is telling me that "Every derived table must have its own alias". Here's my code:

```
UPDATE `t inventory` i INNER JOIN
(SELECT Sum(p.Qty) AS SumOfQty, p.Category AS Category, p.StockNu AS StockNu
FROM `t purchorderitems` p INNER JOIN `t jobenv` j ON p.`Order Nu` = j.`Auto Number`)
WHERE ((p.PickedUp) Is Null AND (j.`Date In`) Is Null AND (p.StockItem)='Yes' AND p.Return=0 AND p.TradeIn=0 AND ((`Locked`) Is Null Or `TransType`='LW'))
Group By p.Category, p.StockNu) x ON (x.StockNu = i.STOCKNO) AND (x.Category = i.ABR)
SET i.NumHld = x.`SumOfQty`;
```

Comment: A naming convention such as this will, in the fairly near future, drive you completely insane.

Comment: I understand your issue with my naming conventions. Unfortunately, the tables I am working with were developed by someone else a long time ago and it is quite difficult to change the names of table fields while those tables are being used. I am slowly migrating my table field names to less confusing and more programmer friendly ones, but it is a slow and involved process.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of writing this question, I managed to find the solution to my own problem. I was indeed quite close to getting the query to work. Apparently, the only thing I had wrong was that I had placed an extra parentheses after `` j.`Auto Number` ``. I removed that parentheses and now the code runs fine.

I thought about not posting since I had managed to figure out my own problem, but since I was having difficulty finding an answer when I searched for this issue, I figured I might as well post my problem and its answer.

Here is the successful code:

```
UPDATE `t inventory1` i INNER JOIN
(SELECT Sum(p.Qty) AS SumOfQty, p.Category AS Category, p.StockNu AS StockNu
FROM `t purchorderitems` p INNER JOIN `t jobenv` j ON p.`Order Nu` = j.`Auto Number`
WHERE ((p.PickedUp) Is Null AND (j.`Date In`) Is Null AND (p.StockItem)='Yes' AND p.Return=0 AND p.TradeIn=0 AND ((`Locked`) Is Null Or `TransType`='LW'))
Group By p.Category, p.StockNu) x ON (x.StockNu = i.STOCKNO) AND (x.Category = i.ABR)
SET i.NumHld = x.`SumOfQty`;
```